# Superclasses and layouts android

Tags: android

I got a superclass like this:

```
public class SuperClass extends Activity
```

and a child class

```
 public class ChildClass extends SuperClass
```

The SuperClass contains a function to set a layout

```
public void setTabBar(String layout){
    inflater.inflate(...., ...); 
}
```

The only thing that different in my child class and superclass is the layout. So over to my question:

Is there anyway I can send a String to the superclass method `setTabBar("name of the layout")`; and then spesify the layout. I'v tried this:

```
public void setTabBar(String layout) {

        int layoutFromString = Integer.parseInt("R.layout."+layout);
        inflater.inflate(layoutFromString, null);
}
```

But this doesnt seems to work. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

As mentioned I tried this:

```
  public void setTabBar(int id) {
     inflater.inflate(id, null);
  }
```

This **will** work for the SuperClass, but when I call the function from the child class like this:

```
public class TestClass extends SuperClass{

  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTabBar(R.layout.test); 

  }
}
```

LogCat only outputs this:

```
07-23 13:57:15.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7329):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
```

Comment: have you considered sending Context of the child activity as an argument as well and then using it while inflating the layout?

Comment: I haven't. Could you provide an example of this?

Comment: Check out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579635/common-header-in-different-activities-using-baseactivity-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to parse an integer from the string passed in to setTabBar.  Reflection would be required to convert the variable name to the actual value, and I personally wouldn't want to tread down that rabbit hole.

Why not just specify that the parameter passed in is an integer?

```
public void setTabBar(int layoutId) {
    inflater.inflate(....,....);
}
```

And, in the calling class:

```
activity.setTabBar(R.layout.nifty_layout);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int layoutFromString = Integer.parseInt("R.layout."+layout);
```

gives you a NumberFormatException, because String "R.layout.yourLayoutId" not a number, its String.
To find id for layoutName use:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME",
                "layout", context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this will work, but I accepted Kevin Wallace's answer because this helped me out better. I upvoted your answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
public abstract class SuperClass extends Activity{
    public void setTabBar(String layout){
        inflater.inflate(getResId(), null); 
    }

    protected abstract int getResId();
}

public class ChildClass extends SuperClass{
    @Override
    protected abstract int getResId(){
        return R.layout.child;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is what you wanted. I hope this will help you.