# How to extend a base activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

I create a option menu in android activity. I have many activity i want the same option menu in all activity. i know i have to create a base activity and extend it but i don't know how. here is my main activity code....

```
            package com.officextracts.kaspersky;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ImageButton;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
        {

            Button Button01;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Button01 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                Button01.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            private void button1Click()
            {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.officextracts.kaspersky.Retail_products"));

            }

            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId())
                {
                case R.id.Button01:
                    button1Click();
                    break;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
            {

                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                case R.id.menu_home:
                    // Single menu item is selected do something
                    // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home Is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_krp:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Kaspersky Retail Products", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_kep:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Kaspersky Endpoint Products", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_fkr:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Find Kaspersky Resaller", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_sales:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contact Kaspersky Sales", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_crs:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contact Retail Support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_ces:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contact Enterprise Support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true; 

                case R.id.menu_coo:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contact Our Office", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;


                case R.id.menu_sms:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS for Support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;


                case R.id.menu_email:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email Support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;            

                case R.id.menu_exit:
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);                

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }
            }    
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8821459/2382964

Answer (score 6):

Create an activity which can be an `abstract` class extending `Activity`. Now each new `Activity` has to extend that class. Eg:

```
//Your base class, where you can have your Action bar and other the other methods which you want all your other classes to inherit
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends Activity{}
 

// You all other classes
public class FirstActivity extends AbstractActivity{}
public class SecondActivity extends AbstractActivity{}
```

See [android how to create my own Activity and extend it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821240/android-how-to-create-my-own-activity-and-extend-it) question

[Common Header in different activities using BaseActivity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579635/common-header-in-different-activities-using-baseactivity-in-android)

[Android: Base Activity class Example](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/android-base-activity-class-example/)
for more.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You Just have to extend `main activity` in other activities.

Your flow will be:
`MainActivity(Super class)->OtherActivities(Subclass)//Which extends MainActivity`