# Reusing the common layout in android application

Tags: android, android-fragments, architecture, android-viewpager

I am trying to make an application that has the following design.

Login->Dashboard

Dashboard has a #navigationdrawer having a listview ,of which every item opens a fragment.

Dashboard has a view pager of two pages.

Page 1 : listview
Page2: search bar.

Till now this is in place.

## Problem statement :

The #page2 is constant it has to appear on every fragment ,but #page1 changes for every fragment . Can someone help me achieve this.

I am not getting how to do it.

Comment: viewpager is needed across all fragments?

Comment: Viewpager is needed but page1 changes on every fragment but page2 is constant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use search menu item in Dashboard's ActionBar instead of fragment and display it using viewpager. Check following link to make search interface.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html