# How to change Android status bar color in all activities together

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-statusbar

I learned how to color an Android activity status bar thanks to this solution: [How to change status bar color to match app in Lollipop? [Android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093287/how-to-change-status-bar-color-to-match-app-in-lollipop-android)

However it doesn't say how to make this for the entire app (all activities).
i don't want to duplicate those 4 lines of code into each Activity, and if I make a Java class for Utils, I can't reach my colors by using R.color.blue or getResources(....).

Is there a way to do this through the Manifest, perhaps? Or any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you read the second answer in the link you posted regarding styles?

Comment: You dont have to add all of those lines, check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579635/common-header-in-different-activities-using-baseactivity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own style in values/styles.xml. Then make your own theme with such parameters. Loock code below

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item><!--this is what you need-->
</style>
```

Or just use method (for Lolipop):

```
public abstract void setStatusBarColor (int color)
```